# The principle of finite choice for a single set family (ZF)

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Is the below a correct proof of the fact that it is possible to choose from a single-element family in ZF (no axiom of choice!) set theory? If it is not, what is the exact point at which it breaks?
**Definition.** $(a,b) := \{\{a, b\}, \{b\}\}$
**Axioms.**
**1. Axiom of pairing.** $\forall A \forall B \exists C \forall D[D \in C \iff (D=A \lor D=B)]$
**2. Axiom of union.** $\forall A \exists B \forall C [C \in B \iff \exists D (C \in D\  \land D \in A)]$
**3. Axiom of extensionality.** $\forall A \forall B [\forall X (X \in A \iff X \in B) \implies A=B]$
**Theorem.** Let $X \ne \emptyset$, and let $F = \{X\}$ be a single-element family consisting of $X$. There exists a function $f: F \rightarrow \bigcup F$, such that $f(X)$ is an element of $X$. 
**Proof.**
**We treat $X$ as given.**
From the assumption that $X \ne \emptyset$ , we have
$$\neg (\forall A [\neg (A \in X)] \ (1)$$ 
By the rules of FOL:
$$\exists A (A \in X) \ (2)$$
By the axiom of pairing:
$$\exists \{A, A\} (A \in X) \ (3)$$
By the axiom of extensionality:
$$\exists \{A\} (A \in X)\ (4)\ $$
By the axiom of pairing and the existence of $X$:
$$\exists \{X\}\ (5)$$
By the axiom of pairing, existence of $X$ and (2):
$$\exists (A \in X) \exists \{ X, A \}\ (6)$$
By the axiom of pairing, (5) and (6)
$$\exists (A \in X) \exists \{\{X\}, \{X, A\}\} \ (7)$$
By the definition of an ordered pair:
$$\exists (A \in X) \exists \{(X, A) \}\ (8)$$
Now, the set ${ (X, A) }$ is exactly the desired function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice! Four remarks.

- I think you mistyped in the definition of ordered pair: you used $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ at the end of your proof.
- (4) follows already from the axiom of pairing.
- You didn't actually use (3) or (4) so you can leave them out!
- To be fully precise, $\{(X,A)\}$ as in (8) is the desired function, not $(X,A)$.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that the definition of an ordered pair should be changed as you said. I don't think that (4) follows from the axiom of pairing - it's natural to us that {W, W} = {W} but that fact is in fact a consequence of the axiom of extensionality, do you agree? It's true that I don't use (3) and (4), in fact I should've put X there. And yes, I see that the desired function is {(X,A)} and not (X,A).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I do agree that $\{W,W\}=\{W\}$ makes use of the axiom of extensionality. However, regarding (4), your axiom of pairing says that there is a set $C$ such that $\forall D:D\in C\Leftrightarrow(D=A\vee D=A)$. The right-hand side simplifies to $D=A$, so $C$ is a set $\{A\}$ just like what (4) claims. You need the axiom of extensionality to prove that every set $\{A\}$ is equal. I hope that I'm not confused or confusing.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks again.